# Cannot uninstall the LanguagePack 0 because it is not deployed

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell, custom-web-parts

I'm trying to run the following PS command on a SharePoint 2010 Foundation Farm:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity testwebpart.wsp -LiteralPath C:\ChrisProjects\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\bin\Debug\TestWebPart.wsp -GACDeployment
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Update-SPSolution : Cannot uninstall the LanguagePack 0 because it is
>   not deployed. At line:1 char:18
>   + Update-SPSolution <<<<  -Identity testwebpart.wsp -LiteralPath C:\ChrisProjects\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\b
>   in\Debug\TestWebPart.wsp -GACDeployment
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tUpdateSolution:SPCmdletUpdateSolution)
>   [Update-SPSoluti    on], SPCmdletException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUpdateSolution

I'm looking everywhere for a resolution, but can't find one...  I tried restarting the SharePoint 2010 Admin/Timer services, nothing.  I tried removing the wsp, but couldn't do it.  I tried deploying through CA, that errored out saying the feature had already been installed.  Not sure what to do at this point.

I can remove the solution through CA.  I then go back to VS, rebuild the wsp and run the following command to get it back on the farm:

```
stsadm -o addsolution -filename C:\ChrisProjects\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\TestWebPart\bin\Debug\TestWebPart.wsp
```

I go back to Central Admin, and there it sits.  Then, when I go in to Deploy it, I get this message:

> A feature with ID ab488346-be08-4a61-aabf-abad966ba10c has already
>   been installed in this farm.  Use the force attribute to explicitly
>   re-install the feature.

I am SO lost... I really hate SharePoint.

***UPDATE***

I'm not really sure why or how, but all of a sudden it's working.  I just tried to remove and then readd the package, following the exact same steps above, which I had already done 5 times, and it suddenly worked.

Albert Einstein once said, *"Insanity is doing the same task repetitively expecting a different result"*.  Obviously, Mr. Einstein has never worked with SharePoint.

Comment: I like your quot.. haha

Answer (score 1):

try the following steps

1. Checked the solution store(Central Administration–>System Settings–> Manage farm solutions) and saw that the solution I was updating was not deployed and thrown error. The error it gave was not able to do GAC diployment of the dll. So i went to GAC and uninstall the WSPs related dlls  and deployed the wsps again from central admin.
2. From services.msc I stopped and restarted the SharePoint 2010 Timer service and the SharePoint 2010 Administration service.
3. Then i ran the power shell command again. this time the WSP got updated.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kunal_mukherjee/2012/11/12/error-cannot-uninstall-language-pack-0-because-it-is-not-deployed-when-attempting-to-uninstall-spsolution-on-sharepoint-2010-foundation/

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and solved doing:

- Retract and then Remove of the wsp from: *Central Administration–>System Settings–> Manage farm solutions.*
- Then, from Powershell, I have canceled the Features with null scope (which were preventing me to install again the package succesfully):

  Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }

  $feature = Get-SPFeature | ? { $_.Scope -eq $null }

  $feature.Delete()
- And at the end I have installed again the wsp:

  Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath *Path*

  Install-SPSolution -Identity *Name.wsp* -WebApplication *WebApplicationPath* –GACDeployment

Then it worked :)